# Is there a better way to implement pointer_traits::rebind?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

I can implement `pointer_traits<Ptr>::element_type` by building a class named `may_element_type`. If the `Ptr` meets the requirements, `may_element_type` will have a type member named `element_type`, otherwise, `may_element_type` will have nothing. And then, `pointer_traits` could inherit `may_element_type`.

But `pointer_traits::rebind` is a template. If I want to do some conditional judgment, `pointer_traits` couldn't inherit a class like `may_rebind`.

I could also use `template <typename T> rebind = may_rebind<T, Ptr>::type`, but there may be nothing in `may_rebind`.

So my question is is there a better way to implement `pointer_traits::rebind`?

Comment: `pointer_traits couldn't inherit a class like may_rebind` I don't see any reason why a class can't inherit a member template from its base class. What problem, exactly, have you encountered when you tried this approach?

Comment: @IgorTandetnik `pointer_traits` only has one template parameter `Ptr`, but `rebind` also needs another template parameter because it is a template member and the judgment that if `may_rebind` includes `rebind` also needs `Ptr` and another template parameter.

Comment: `may_rebind` would have a member template alias, just like `may_element_type` would have a member type. You can't have `rebind<U>` present for some `U`, and somehow have it absent for other `U`; the best you can do is to have it fail to instantiate for those "bad" `U` (e.g. with `static_assert`) It's possible I misunderstand what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik You don't misunderstand my thought, thanks.